# Outlook 2010: Show an 'outside working hours' notification when composing mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Here's the situation. 
A friend freelances for an organization, and she wants to control mails she receives outside of working hours.
Normally Outlook displays a sort of popup when you're composing mail to someone whose 'Out of office' is active (as does Lync 2010). 
She wants a similar way to notify someone who is composing a mail to her, if that person is composing the mail outside of her office hours.

The second suboptimal solution is to have an autoresponse sent for incoming mail sent outside working hours, say after 6 PM. However,there don't seem to be rule criteria for rules based on the time an email was received.

Is there a way to do this, perhaps by some third party addon?

Comment: But how? I haven't actually got satisfactory answers on the questions I've asked; and they don't seem to be very specialized questions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly work around for 2010:

In Outlook 2010 -> Tools -> Rules and Alerts
New rule -> Start with a blank rule -> Check messages when they arrive
Check 'with specific words in the message header'
The words to look for would be "18:","19:","20:" etc to trigger for mail arriving between 6pm and 8pm.

The advice below is for Office 365 - it may work in 2010 and Exchange but not sure.

As a workaround, the user can try to set a MailTips (I am off of the office from 10pm to 7am) in Office 365 to achieve this goal. When a sender sends emails to him, the MailTips will be displayed in the Outlook Web App compose note as a banner. For more information, see http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ff872400.aspx

Answer (score -1):

welcome to 2023.
The link above doens't work anymore.
Is this possible in Outlook (also web+mobile) today?
Mailtips can't be activated during specific hours.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).